# AttributeError: module 'meep' has no attribute 'Vector3'

Tags: python, meep

I've installed [pymeep](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pymeep) using the anaconda environment. Unfortunately, when I use Spyder to try to run use a Vector3 class from meep i get the error:

AttributeError: module 'meep' has no attribute 'Vector3'

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? I have already tried using the recommended environment:

```
conda create -n mp -c chogan -c defaults -c conda-forge pymeep
```

to no use.

The code where I'm using this is the first tutorial/example from [here:](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python_Tutorials/Basics/)

```
import meep as mp
cell = mp.Vector3(16, 8, 0)
geometry = [mp.Block(mp.Vector3(1e20, 1, 1e20),
                     center=mp.Vector3(0, 0),
                     material=mp.Medium(epsilon=12))]

sources = [mp.Source(mp.ContinuousSource(frequency=0.15),
                     component=mp.Ez,
                     center=mp.Vector3(-7,0))]

pml_layers = [mp.PML(1.0)]

resolution = 10

sim = mp.Simulation(cell_size=cell,
                    boundary_layers=pml_layers,
                    geometry=geometry,
                    sources=sources,
                    resolution=resolution)

sim.run(until=200)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector3 in Meep in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867259/vector3-in-meep-in-python)

Comment: It is not. I've tried the suggested solution in that thread with no result.

Comment: Please paste the code where you try to use the vector3.

Comment: @Guimoute added code

Comment: Thanks. I just installed meep to see and... it has no interesting attributes showing when I try to autocomplete. I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, that happens to me too, but since I am very new at Python, I assumed some libraries autocomplete and some don't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and everything worked properly once I started using python2 instead of python3.